# GeckoFX - implement search function - how to use nsIWebBrowserFind interface

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

Could anyone perhaps tell me how should I use the nsIWebBrowserFind interface in GeckoFX to find strings on a webpage?

I tried the following code, but this throws me an ArgumentNullException - parameter cannot be null (pUnk).

I have no idea what this means, I have never used interfaces before.

```
        GeckoWebBrowser browser = getCurrentBrowser();

        nsIWebBrowserFind finder = browser.GetInterface<nsIWebBrowserFind>();

        finder.SetSearchStringAttribute(searchBox1.Text);
        finder.FindNext();
```

I have also tried

```
    nsIWebBrowserFind finder = Gecko.Xpcom.GetInterface<nsIWebBrowserFind>(browser);
```

With the same results:(

Please help:)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more specif about which actual line throws the InvalidArgumentException in the first code example. Also does the second code really throw a InvalidArgumentException, not some other exception?

Comment: Hi Tom!
The line that throws the exception is `nsIWebBrowserFind find = browser.GetInterface<nsIWebBrowserFind>();`.And both codes throw Argument Null Exception, sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 1):

This works in GeckoFX 29.0:

```
var field = typeof(GeckoWebBrowser).GetField("WebBrowser", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
nsIWebBrowser browser = (nsIWebBrowser)field.GetValue(webBrowser1);
var browserFind = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIWebBrowserFind>(browser);
browserFind.SetSearchStringAttribute(search);
try
{
browserFind.SetWrapFindAttribute(true);
browserFind.FindNext();
}
catch { }
```

Some websites with frames throws an exception after the last result however, this seems to be a bug in GeckoFX. We did a workaround by falling back to a javascript find (javascript:window.find) when the exception was thrown.

Comment: You, Sire have my upvote:) Can you tell me if you know whether it is possible to 'highlight all matches'?
Also - what is the javascript.find solution you have applied?